# To display all the months from a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-date-functions

Just wanted your help. I have start date and end date and I want to display all the months between them using SQL.

Can anyone please let me know how can we do this?
If I have start date as 12-09-2022 and end date as 05-05-2023 so I am expecting the output as :

```
Sep -2022
Oct-2022
Nov- 2022
.
.
.
.
March-2023
Apr-2023
May-2023
```

Comment: sounds like you want to generate a date dimension

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: What database is this

Comment: SQL server, or MY SQL

Answer (score 0):

For Mariadb you can use this using a sequence generator seq_1_to_12 . seq_n_to_x is Mariadb specific, but I am sure other db will have similar mechanism.
You just need the difference between the start and the end date and keep on adding the month.

```html
 With a as (select str_to_date('12-09-2022','%d-%m-%Y')start_date,str_to_date('05-05-2023','%d-%m-%Y') end_date) Select date_format(date_add(start_date, interval seq month),'%M - %Y')  date from a join seq_0_to_12 where date_add(start_date, interval seq month) <= date_add(end_date , interval 1 month) ;
+------------------+
| date             |
+------------------+
| September - 2022 |
| October - 2022   |
| November - 2022  |
| December - 2022  |
| January - 2023   |
| February - 2023  |
| March - 2023     |
| April - 2023     |
| May - 2023       |
+------------------+
```

code here

Comment: can you please let me know what will be the code for SQL server, Or My SQL or Oracle